# Creating new column based on the other columns blank values in R Program

Tags: r

My data

```
Type1   Type2   Type3       Expected_Output                 
Red     Orange  Pink        Pink                
Green   abc     na          abc             
Blue     na     na          Blue                
white    na     Green       Green               
na     Brown    purple      purple              
na     black     na         black               
grey    na       na         grey
```

How to Achieve the following expected output:

1. If type3 is filled than expected output should be type3's content
2. If type2 is filled and type3 is blank(na) than expected output should be type2's content
3. If type3 and type2 is blank(na) than expcetd output should be
   type1's content

Comment: Something like `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df, ties.method = "last"))]` should do. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You have to mention how your data are represented in R. I take the blanks are NA's?

Comment: yes blanks can be considered as na's @ Disco

Answer (score 2):

A data.frame which consists of multiple columns of the same data type is an indication that the data might be reshaped from wide to long format. Therefore, `melt()` is used to get rid of the `NA`s and *join* to add the new column to the original data.frame:

```
library(data.table)
DT[melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn", na.rm = TRUE)[
    order(variable), .(New = last(value)), by = rn], on = .(rn)][, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    Type1  Type2  Type3 Expected_Output    New
> 1:   Red Orange   Pink            Pink   Pink
> 2: Green    abc     NA             abc    abc
> 3:  Blue     NA     NA            Blue   Blue
> 4: white     NA  Green           Green  Green
> 5:    NA  Brown purple          purple   grey
> 6:    NA  black     NA           black purple
> 7:  grey     NA     NA            grey  black
> ```

#### Data

`fread()` is used to read the sample data set. The `na.strings` parameter tells `fread()` to convert the `"na"` strings to `NA`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"Type1   Type2   Type3       Expected_Output                 
Red     Orange  Pink        Pink                
Green   abc     na          abc             
Blue     na     na          Blue                
white    na     Green       Green               
na     Brown    purple      purple              
na     black     na         black               
grey    na       na         grey    ",
na.strings = "na")
```

#### Edit

[The OP has requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885063/creating-new-column-based-on-the-other-columns-blank-values-in-r-program#comment77166609_44886368) that also lines which are fully `NA` should appear in the output. This can be achieved by changing the order of `data.table` objects in the right join. In `data.table` syntax, `X[Y]` is a right join which takes all rows of `Y`. If all rows of `X` are required, the right join `Y[X]` has to be used

```
library(data.table)
# new data with 8th row
DT <- fread(
  "Type1   Type2   Type3       Expected_Output                 
  Red     Orange  Pink        Pink                
  Green   abc     na          abc             
  Blue     na     na          Blue                
  white    na     Green       Green               
  na     Brown    purple      purple              
  na     black     na         black               
  grey    na       na         grey    
  na      na       na         na",
  na.strings = "na")

melt(DT[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn", na.rm = TRUE)[
  order(variable), .(New = last(value)), by = rn][DT, on = .(rn)][, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>       New Type1  Type2  Type3 Expected_Output
> 1:   Pink   Red Orange   Pink            Pink
> 2:    abc Green    abc     NA             abc
> 3:   Blue  Blue     NA     NA            Blue
> 4:  Green white     NA  Green           Green
> 5: purple    NA  Brown purple          purple
> 6:  black    NA  black     NA           black
> 7:   grey  grey     NA     NA            grey
> 8:     NA    NA     NA     NA              NA
> ```

Comment: if suppose i have 8th row as Type1 - NA , Type2 -NA , Type3- NA , I wnt the Exp_Output to be NA only , but the above code will erase the 8th record itself

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `last` from `dplyr` inside an `apply` call. Make sure your `na` are `NA` so that `na.omit` ignores them.

```
library(dplyr)
df[df=="na"] <- NA #change "na" to NA
df$expected2 <-apply(df[,1:3],1,function(x) last(na.omit(x)))

  Type1  Type2  Type3 Expected_Output expected2
1   Red Orange   Pink            Pink      Pink
2 Green    abc   <NA>             abc       abc
3  Blue   <NA>   <NA>            Blue      Blue
4 white   <NA>  Green           Green     Green
5  <NA>  Brown purple          purple    purple
6  <NA>  black   <NA>           black     black
7  grey   <NA>   <NA>            grey      grey
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="Type1   Type2   Type3 Expected_Output                 
Red     Orange  Pink        Pink                
                 Green   abc     na          abc             
                 Blue     na     na          Blue                
                 white    na     Green       Green               
                 na     Brown    purple      purple              
                 na     black     na         black               
                 grey    na       na         grey ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: hi @ P Lapointe am getting error message when i try the same code today ,Error message - Error: Don't know how to generate default for object of class character - how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution based on ifelse; hope it helps.

```
DT$new <- ifelse(is.na(DT$Type3), ifelse(is.na(DT$Type2),DT$Type1,DT$Type2),DT$Type3)
```

[image]